# Optional recipients esign (Docusign)

Tags: docusignapi

I am using esign 4.1.0 and I am trying to create an envelope with sign order.
I've got 2 groups of signers, and I only need that someone of each group sign the envelope.
it means:
signing order 1 -> groupA = ['John', 'Peter']
signing order 2 -> groupB = ['Sarah', 'Kelly']

For considering the envelope signed i need that signs the envelope (John OR Peter ) AND (Sarah OR Kelly). Is it possible? I've tried using optional signature, but it havent worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The feature that will enable this scenario is called "Signing Group" and you need to first set up a [signing group](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=gav1643676262430&topicId=zgn1578456447934.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301=), then add it to your envelope.

The first thing is discussed in this blog post - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-create-a-signing-group
The second part is in https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-requesting-signature-signing-group

You didn't indicate which particular lang you're using, so I didn't provide code snippets here.